# Understanding the differences in dielectric functions derived from various methods

Tags: condensed-matter, polarization, dielectric, many-body, optical-materials

I am currently investigating the response of a specific system to an external electric field and have encountered a question that has puzzled me for a long time.

Consider a system subjected to alternating electric fields represented by $\vec{E}(t) = \int \rm{d} \omega \vec{E}(\omega) e^{i \omega t}$. Expanding the energy E with respect to $\vec{E}$, we obtain explicit expressions for the dipole moment, linear polarizability, and hyperpolarizability as the order increases:
$$\varepsilon(\vec{E}) = \varepsilon(0) - \vec{\mu} \cdot \vec{E} - 1/2 \alpha \vec{E} \vec{E} - \cdots $$
In the dipole approximation, the total electric field is approximately equal to $\vec{\mu}$. By differentiating with respect to the electric field, we can gather information about the linear polarizability $\alpha$ and hyperpolarizability. It's evident that if the dipole moment is real, then $\alpha(\omega)$ and the real part of the dielectric function $\epsilon_{real}(\omega)$ are also real.

However, in most cases, the dielectric function is a complex number due to attenuation along the electromagnetic wave's propagation direction. This is also reflected in the complex dielectric function $\epsilon_{complex}$ calculated using the GW-BSE method.

My question is about the distinctions between the dielectric functions derived from these two methods. Is the real part of $\epsilon_{real}$ simply the real component of $\epsilon_{complex}$?

Furthermore, what did the earlier method neglect, resulting in the omission of electromagnetic field attenuation and absorption?

Comment: My thought is that $\epsilon_{real}(\vec{r}, \omega)$ is a function of position and frequency, corresponding to the response at the same spatial location. Hence, it does not include information about attenuation like $\epsilon_{complex}(\vec{q}, \omega)$, which fully describes the dielectric function varying across space. I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: $E$ is both energy and electric field? Maybe try to change one of those two to varepsilon or any other letter

Comment: Real permittivity is valid only in static field, for any oscillating field there will be a phase shift between field and polarization, and the linear relation with real permittivity does not apply. Complex permittivity is more general and applies to harmonically oscillating field.

Comment: Thank you to Mr./Ms. Mauricio for the helpful advice. Indeed, using $\vec{E}$ and $E$ together may cause confusion, so I have switched to using $\varepsilon$ to denote energy.


Also, as Mr./Ms. Ján Lalinský kindly pointed out, there is a phase shift between the original field and polarization in an oscillating field. However, the previous method for deriving linear polarizability was also based on the oscillating case. I am unclear why it fails to account for the information regarding the phase shift.